# What to change in list sorting to sort it properly

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I can't sort my list entirely. It's int based sorting and I used CompareTo() form IComparable, custom Comparer delegate, and anonymous delegate. None of this work for me.

here is the code:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void SortingPlayersFirst()
    {
      //arrange
      Player player = new Player("neosb");
      Player player2 = new Player("simone");
      Player player3 = new Player("Alice");
      player.Score = 5;
      player2.Score = 2;
      player3.Score = 10;
      Players players = new Players();
      players.Add(player);
      players.Add(player2);
      players.Add(player3);

      //I have tried this one
      players.Sort(Player.ComparePlayersByScore);
      //and this one
      players.Sort()
      // and this one
      IComparer<Player> comp = Comparer<Player>.Create(
        (p1, p2) => p1.Score.CompareTo(p2.Score));
      players.Sort(comp);

      //this one fails the test
      Assert.AreEqual(player3, players[0], "Highest score is not first");
      //however this one passes the test
      Assert.AreNotEqual(player2, players[2], "Lowest score is not last");
    }

public class Players : List<Player>
  {

  }

public class Player : IComparable<Player>, IEquatable<Player>
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public Player(string name)
    {
      Name = name;
      Score = 0;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Player other)
    {
      return Score.CompareTo(other.Score);
    }

    public static int ComparePlayersByScore(Player player1, Player player2)
    {
      if (player1.Score > player2.Score)
        return 1;
      else if (player1.Score < player2.Score)
        return -1;
      else
        return 0;
    }
  }
```

what do I have to do to sort this list and pass the unit test and why it's partly sorted.

Comment: Just a side note - testing `List.Sort` seems redundant. It's already been tested by Microsoft. Testing the `CompareTo` and `ComparePlayersByScore` method only requires two `Player`s and would be a much easier test to read and understand.

Comment: Where's your comparer?

Comment: comparer is in Player class - ComparePlayersByScore(), I know it should outside in delegate class, but for simplicity I put it there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're sorting it in *ascending* order, rather than descending... but your test requires that the *highest* scoring player is first. This should work:

```
// Use the overload taking a Comparer<Player> delegate for simplicity
players.Sort((p1, p2) => p2.Score.CompareTo(p1.Score));
```

Note the reversal of the use of `p1` and `p2` in the lambda expression - that's how you reverse the comparison.

Comment: beside sorting in ascending order, I wrote the bad second assert, where is Assert.AreNotEqual(), should be Assert.AreEqual() and it led me to confusion as one Player was in place. Thus the list.Reverse() didn't passed the test. Thank you, you woke me up this morning.